# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when saving file on server

Tags: c#, .net

I know that this error has more awnsers on this form but none seem to be working since they are having problems with localhost. But localhost works fine for me.

I'm trying to create a .xlsx file from a button click on the server.

I already contacted the hosting company to make sure that it is possible to place files like this on there server and they told me that I could. So.... that is not the probleme.

This works perfect on localhost. But when I move it to the webhost I get this error:

[image]

I use this code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // local path
                    //string path = @"D:\local\Test\order.xlsx";
                    
                    // Server path
                    string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\Excel-Exports\order.xlsx");
                    workbook.SaveAs(path);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();

                    File(
                        content,
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                        "order.xlsx");
                }
```

Before this part of code I build the Excel file. So I don't think that is the probleme.

I think the probleme is with the path since the tells me that I cant not find the file.

For the record I do use the same method for reaching a path on a different location and this works just fine.

**Working code on other location**

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/img/MetropolisGO_RGB-kleur1.png");
            LinkedResource Img = new LinkedResource(path);
```

Does anyone have a solution for me to save this file on the server?

Comment: No, the problem is with finding the dependency ClosedXML. That's not the file you're trying to save, it's a library

Comment: That error indicates that the dll ```ClosedXML``` cannot be found, that's not about your file.

Comment: OOOOOOW. That explains everything. Thank you so much guys. I will go after this then. Man I feel stupid

Comment: A client connecting to the server by default only has GUEST privilege and cannot read/write the server filesystem.  You may want to use FTP to upload file.

Comment: fixed it by uploading the packages that where missing. So It works now and I learned something thank you. I can't flag a comment for correct but I will add it in the question. Thank you

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the project is missing "ClosedXML" version 0.95.4 that is reference or using it but there is no DLL or library or project to be used.

If it's in your project, check the order of the building.
If is third-party, check the DLL or library is "copy always" in the build